# Error Code: 1054 Unknown column in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to fetch total views of every artist all contents

`wp_content_details.artist_id = wp_artist.id` is generating the error '`Unknown column  in where clause`' when i use static value `wp_content_details.artist_id = 29` then its ok but i need to use the condition  `wp_content_details.artist_id = wp_artist.id`

```
SELECT wp_artist.id
    ,wp_artist.NAME
    ,(
        SELECT SUM(total_user) AS total_view
        FROM (
            SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT (user_id)) AS total_user
            FROM wp_views
            LEFT JOIN wp_content_details ON wp_content_details.content_id = wp_views.content_id
            WHERE wp_content_details.artist_id = wp_artist.id /* Its ok if use:  wp_content_details.artist_id = 29*/
                AND wp_content_details.role_id = 2
            GROUP BY wp_views.content_id
            ) content_views
        ) AS total_views
FROM wp_artist
WHERE wp_artist.id IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT (wp_content_details.artist_id)
        FROM wp_content_details
        WHERE wp_content_details.artist_id = wp_artist.id
            AND wp_content_details.role_id = 2
        )
ORDER BY total_views DESC
    ,wp_artist.NAME ASC
```

Please help me. If you have any confusion please ask me.

Comment: The subquery only has access to the tables in its own FROM clause, not those outside the subquery. That's why it doesn't know what table wp_artist is. You'd have to include wp_artist in the FROM clause of your subquery. This is a pretty complex query so it's hard for me to rewrite it for you and ensure that the logic is right for what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: [chris-flynn](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2077561/chris-flynn) i appreciate you.  if i use wp_artist in subquery then it will not meet the condition for main query artist id

Comment: This looks awkward to me,use proper JOINs and CASE,it will be clearer,nevermind the likely speed improvements.

Comment: [mihai](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1745672/mihai) i am working in a project where database designed one year ago. So cant change database structure. This is the query best i can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wp_artist.ID is out of scope. Try

```
    SELECT SUM(total_user) AS total_view
    FROM (
        SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT (user_id)) AS total_user, wp_content_details.artist_id
        FROM wp_views
        LEFT JOIN wp_content_details ON wp_content_details.content_id = wp_views.content_id
        WHERE wp_content_details.role_id = 2
        GROUP BY wp_views.content_id, wp_content_details.artist_id 
        ) content_views
Where content_views.artist_id = wp_artist.id
    ) AS total_views
```

Comment: I dont understand why i will join wp_artist with wp_images When my problem is in last subquery wp_views alias total_views